# Statistic of cubic Irreducible polynomial with cyclic Galois group   

Tags: tag-removed, nt.number-theory

Van der Waerden proved for monic irreducible polynomials $f$ of degree $n$ with bounded height $X$:
$$
|\{ f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]: Gal(f)\neq S_n \}|=o(X)
$$
Where height of $f$ is defined by maximum of absolute value of its coefficient.

So if we order monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ with respect to height, then we expect to obtain symmetric group as its Galois group. Now what if we want to replace height by discriminant.

Do we have any table or any conjecture about this? More precisely is it true:

$$
|\{ f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]: monic, irreducible \deg(f)=n, |Disc(f)|\leq X, Gal(f)\neq S_n\}|=o(X)
$$

Comment: You might find the slides for Carl Pomerance's talk on counting fields to be relevant: http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/rademacherlecture4.pdf


Comment: There are dozens of recent articles relevant to this question; Bhargava, Belabas, Cohen, ... Perhaps a good place to start is
Cohem, Diaz y Diaz,  Olivier: "A survey of discriminant counting" in ANTS-V.

Comment: @myself: I meant Cohen, not Cohem.

As for Pomerances nice notes mentioned by Ben: the Delone-Faddeev correspondence is actually due to F. Levi, Leipziger Berichte 66 (1914), 26-37. Delone and Faddeev credit him for this in the preface to their book, but it seems to have been overlooked.

Comment: @Franz: I am a bit familiar with Bhargava results, but here I want to count polynomials instead to count number field, I think this would be not exactly similar to counting number field, since different polynomials can give same number field with the same discriminant. Also for example if one look at quartic number field then contribution of $S_4$ and $D_4$ are linear i.e cx. I expect for polynomials contribution of $D_4$ is negligible.

Comment: The conjecture that you stated is almost surely true, in fact one should get a bound of $O(X^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$. Most likely one can prove this as follows: an irreducible cubic polynomial has cyclic Galois group if and only if   there exists an order 3 element in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ which permutes the roots of $f$ via Mobius action. It is not too hard to characterize all order 3 elements in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, and you can check that for a fixed order 3 element $T$ there is a unique monic polynomial whose roots are permuted by $T$.